# filling circle with hexagons

Tags: javascript, html, geometry

I'm trying to find a way to put as much hexagons in a circle as possible. So far the best result I have obtained is by generating hexagons from the center outward in a circular shape.

But I think my calculation to get the **maximum hexagon circles** is wrong, especially the part where I use the `Math.ceil()` and `Math.Floor` functions to round down/up some values.

When using `Math.ceil()`, hexagons are sometimes overlapping the circle.
When using `Math.floor()` on the other hand , it sometimes leaves too much space between the last circle of hexagons and the circle's border.

```js
var c_el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c_el.getContext("2d");

var canvas_width = c_el.clientWidth;
var canvas_height = c_el.clientHeight;

var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;

var hexCircle = {
 r: 110, /// radius 
 pos: {
  x: (canvas_width / 2),
  y: (canvas_height / 2)
 }
};

var hexagon = {
 r: 20,
 pos:{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
 },
 space: 1
};

drawHexCircle( hexCircle, hexagon );
function drawHexCircle(hc, hex ) {
 drawCircle(hc);
 var hcr = Math.ceil( Math.sqrt(3) * (hc.r / 2) ); 
    var hr =  Math.ceil( ( Math.sqrt(3) * (hex.r / 2) ) ) + hexagon.space; // hexRadius
 var circles =  Math.ceil( ( hcr / hr ) / 2 );
    drawHex( hc.pos.x , hc.pos.y, hex.r ); //center hex ///
 for (var i = 1; i<=circles; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j<6; j++) {
   var currentX = hc.pos.x+Math.cos(j*PI2/6)*hr*2*i;
   var currentY = hc.pos.y+Math.sin(j*PI2/6)*hr*2*i;
   drawHex( currentX,currentY, hex.r );
   for (var k = 1; k<i; k++) {
    var newX = currentX + Math.cos((j*PI2/6+PI2/3))*hr*2*k;
    var newY = currentY +  Math.sin((j*PI2/6+PI2/3))*hr*2*k;
    drawHex( newX,newY, hex.r );
   }
  }
 }
}

function drawHex(x, y, r){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x,y-r);
    for (var i = 0; i<=6; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(x+Math.cos((i*PI2/6-PI2/4))*r,y+Math.sin((i*PI2/6-PI2/4))*r);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawCircle( circle ){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(circle.pos.x, circle.pos.y, circle.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="350" height="350" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all the points on the hexagon are within the circle, the hexagon is within the circle.  I don't think there's a simpler way than doing the distance calculation.

I'm not sure how to select the optimal fill point, (but here's a js snippet proving that the middle isn't always it).  It's possible that when you say "hexagon circle" you mean hexagon made out of hexagons, in which case the snippet proves nothing :)

I made the hexagon sides 2/11ths the radius of the circle and spaced them by 5% the side length.

```js
var hex = {x:0, y:0, r:10};
var circle = {x:100, y:100, r:100};
var spacing = 1.05;
var SQRT_3 = Math.sqrt(3);
var hexagon_offsets = [
  {x: 1/2, y: -SQRT_3 / 2},
  {x: 1, y: 0},
  {x: 1/2, y: SQRT_3 / 2},
  {x: -1/2, y: SQRT_3 / 2},
  {x: -1, y: 0},
  {x: -1/2, y: -SQRT_3 / 2}
];


var bs = document.body.style;
var ds = document.documentElement.style;
bs.height = bs.width = ds.height = ds.width = "100%";
bs.border = bs.margin = bs.padding = 0;
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.style.display = "block";
c.addEventListener("mousemove", follow, false);
document.body.appendChild(c);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);
redraw();


function follow(e) {
  hex.x = e.clientX;
  hex.y = e.clientY;
  redraw();
}
function drawCircle() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
function is_in_circle(p) {
  return Math.pow(p.x - circle.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - circle.y, 2) < Math.pow(circle.r, 2);
}
function drawLine(a, b) {
  var within = is_in_circle(a) && is_in_circle(b);
  ctx.strokeStyle = within ? "green": "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
  ctx.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  return within;
}
function drawShape(shape) {
  var within = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < shape.length; i++) {
    within = drawLine(shape[i % shape.length], shape[(i + 1) % shape.length]) && within;
  }
  if (!within) return false;
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(shape[0].x, shape[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i <= shape.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(shape[i % shape.length].x, shape[i % shape.length].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  return true;
}
function calculate_hexagon(x, y, r) {
  return hexagon_offsets.map(function (offset) {
    return {x: x + r * offset.x, y: y + r * offset.y};
  })
}
function drawHexGrid() {
  var hex_count = 0;
  var grid_space = calculate_hexagon(0, 0, hex.r * spacing);
  var y = hex.y;
  var x = hex.x;
  while (y > 0) {
    y += grid_space[0].y * 3;
    x += grid_space[0].x * 3;
  }
  while (y < c.height) {
    x %= grid_space[1].x * 3;
    while (x < c.width) {
      var hexagon = calculate_hexagon(x, y, hex.r);
      if (drawShape(hexagon)) hex_count++;
      x += 3 * grid_space[1].x;
    }
    y += grid_space[3].y;
    x += grid_space[3].x;
    x += 2 * grid_space[1].x;
  }
  return hex_count;
}

function redraw() {
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  circle.x = c.width / 2;
  circle.y = c.height / 2;
  circle.r = Math.min(circle.x, circle.y) * 0.9;
  hex.r = circle.r * (20 / 110);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  var hex_count = drawHexGrid();
  drawCircle();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 50)";
  ctx.font = "40px serif";
  ctx.fillText(hex_count + " hexes within circle", 20, 40);
}
```